# Aggregating daily to weekly data with categorical variables

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, modeling

my question doesn't regard any particular software, it's more of a broad question that could concern every type of data mining problem.

I have a data set with daily data and a bunch of attributes, like the above. 'Sales' is numeric and represents the revenue of sales on a given day. 'Open' is categorical and retrieves if a store is open (=1) or closed (=0). And 'Promo' is categorical, stating if a type of promo is happening at the given day (it takes the values a, b and c).

| day | sales | open | promo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06/12/2022 | 15 | 1 | a |
| 05/12/2022 | 0 | 0 | a |
| 04/12/2022 | 12 | 1 | b |

Now, my goal is to develop a model that predicts **weekly** sales. In order to do this, I will need to aggregate daily data into weekly data.

For the variable **sales** this is quite straight forward because the value of weekly sales is the sum of daily sales within a certain week.

My question regards the categorical variables (open and promo), what kind of aggregation function should I use? I have tried to convert the variables to numerical and use the weekly mean as an aggregation method for this attributes, but i don't know if this is a common approach.

I would like to know if anyone knows what is the best/usual way to tackle this?

Thanks, anyway!